# Creating large PDFs that can't fit in memory all at once

Tags: java, android, pdfbox

I'm using [PdfBox Android](https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android) to create large PDFs.

Each page I create needs to have a number of images added to it. I can guarantee that the number of bitmaps on any one given page can fit in memory, but not for any more than that.

As a result, in certain cases the program crashes with an out-of-memory error because it can't hold all of the bitmaps in memory.

Since I only need to work on one page at a time, in theory it should be possible to flush the pages I don't need to a file (e.g. a temporary scratch file) to free up memory.

I've tried setting the PDDocument MemoryUsageSetting to use a scratch file, but that hasn't worked for me.

As far as I can tell PdfBox loads it's in-memory representation all at once and there's no way for it to flush unused objects to storage.

This is causing a lot of issues for my app, any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the 2.0.* versions, open the PDF like this:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file,MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());
```

This will setup buffering memory usage to only use temporary file(s) (no main-memory) with not restricted size.

Comment: Does this work for creating PDFs rather than loading ones: "PDDocument pdfDoc = new PDDocument(MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly())" instead?

Comment: Still crashes for me.

Comment: Best look into memory allocation and the size of RAM in the machine you are using and how to best configure its stack and heap and Garbage Collector of the JVM.

Comment: Maybe try changing the way you approach the problem ? Why not create the target PDF page by page and then just stich the individual pages together.